# combine two values identified by a name from two files

Tags: unix

ab.txt

```
30 abcd
45 sadsad
```

ac.txt

```
50 ab
430 sadsad
```

how can i join these so that i can get

abc.txt

```
30 abcd
50 ab
475 sadsad
```

Strings in second column are unique though

i tried reading line by line from first txt file and reading the string and searching this with grep in second file and then getting the number from it , in same way reading line by line from second file and get the string which is not in first

but this process is too tiresome and worst possible way,
any nice procedure doing it with join easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work with GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{ sum[$2] += $1 } END { for (name in sum) print sum[name] " " name }' a b |
  sort -n
```

**Explanation:**

As each line is read from the files, the variables `$1` and `$2` contain the first and second fields (that is, the value and the string).  The associative array `sum` uses the strings as its indices, so it accumulates the values associated with each string.  Then, at the end of input (after the last file is read), it loops through the `name` of each string that's an index in `sum`, printing its total and its name.  Finally, it sorts the output numerically.

Comment: one doubt, what if key has spaces in it?
 i mean what if `50 ab
430 sad sad`
i should make one more variable for using it as key ,constructed from remaining fields right? 
will this work?
how can i select all the remaining fields from $2 to $NF?

Comment: You can use the `sub` or `gensub` commands to remove the first field from the string by replacing `/^$1/` with nothing.  Then you can use the remainder of the line as the key.